# Android Studio slow after opening specific Kotlin file

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

In my project (many modules and classes), I have a Kotlin class which is just 30 lines long and consist of one single method.
When I open this file and try to edit it, Android Studio drives crazy and does not respond anymore.
I tried to invalidate caches, clean project etc. but nothing helped.
Any ideas? Does Android Studio creates some hidden files which may be corrupt and may not be cleaned?

I am using Android Studio 4.2.1 on Mac.

** Update: It goes mad when the autocompletion starts while editing.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the file in external text editor (for example just comment out entire content or rename it) to see if it affects behavior inside the studio?

Comment: Yes I already did that because it was the only way to change the file. However when I edit it again in AS, the behavior is still the same.